# Arrange data according to text file sequence

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have one text file that stores **all the criteria** and I have another text file which is **criteria assigned to one person**. So this is all the criteria stored:
**criteria.txt**

```
criteria1|desc1|3
criteria2|desc2|4
criteria3|desc3|4
criteria4|desc4|3
criteria5|desc5|5
```

And this is the criteria assigned to a person:
**criteria2.txt**

```
criteria2|desc2|4
criteria1|desc1|3    
criteria3|desc3|4
```

I want to display the criteria assigned to the person from **criteria2.txt** according to the **criteria.txt** sequence like this:

```
criteria1 #instead of criteria2
criteria2 #instead of criteria1
criteria3 #instead of criteria3
```

I tried the coding below but it prints nothing.

```
while IFS='|' read -r var1 var2 var3
do
grep "$var1" criteria2.txt | cut -f1 -d "|"
done < criteria.txt
```

Edit:
I use this command
`awk -F'|' '{print $1} criteria2.txt | sort`
and the problem is solved but this only sort by the first variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this command
`awk -F'|' '{print $1} criteria2.txt | sort`
and the problem is solved but this only sort by the first variable.